# Codificando un sistema de ecuaciones en un vector y resolver por aproximación

Tags: matemáticas, matlab

Estoy intentando resolveer un sistema de ecuaciones diferenciales por el método de Euler. Primero, reescribo el sistema en forma de vector. Después paso las condiciones iniciales al método.

Sin embargo, hay algo que no fucniona. Este es el error que obtengo.

```
>> programa01
Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 1-by-2 and the size of the right side is 2-by-2.

Error in ode_Euler (line 11)
   y(k+1,:)= y(k,:) +h*feval(f,t(k),y(k,:));

Error in nm06p03a (line 12)
tic, [tE,xE]=ode_Euler(f,tspan,x0,N); t_Euler=toc;
```

Este es mi código hasta ahora.

```
clear, clf
    f=@(t,x)[-x(2)+x(1)*x(2); x(1)-(0.5.*x(1).^2)+(0.5.*x(2).^2)]; %Encoding system of differential equations into a vector
    t0=0; tf=10; 
    tspan=[t0 tf]; 
    N=100;
    x0s=[0.2 0]; % A matrix consisting of initial points
    for iter=1:size(x0s,1)
    x0=x0s(iter,:);
    tic, [tE,xE]=ode_Euler(f,tspan,x0,N); t_Euler=toc;
    subplot(220+iter), 
    plot(tE,xE,'r:')
    legend('ode_ Euler')
    end
```

Aquí el método de Euler:

```
function [t,y]=ode_Euler(f,tspan,y0,N)
if nargin<4|N<=0, N=100; end
if nargin<3, y0=0; end
h=(tspan(2)-tspan(1))/N; 
t=tspan(1)+[0:N]'*h; 
y(1,:)=y0(:)'; %make it a row vector
for k=1:N
   y(k+1,:)= y(k,:) +h*feval(f,t(k),y(k,:));
end
```

Cuando uso el método de Heun con la siguiente función, también obtengo el mismo error:

```
function [t,y]=ode_Heun(f,tspan,y0,N)
if nargin<4|N<=0, N=100; end
if nargin<3, y0=0; end
h=(tspan(2)-tspan(1))/N; % Step-size
t=tspan(1)+[0:N]'*h; % Time vector
y(1,:)=y0(:)'; % make the initial value a row vector
for k=1:N
fk= feval(f,t(k),y(k,:)); y(k+1,:)= y(k,:)+h*fk; % Eq.(6.2.3)
y(k+1,:)= y(k,:) +h/2*(fk +feval(f,t(k+1),y(k+1,:))); % Eq.(6.2.4)
end
```

Puede alguien echarme una mano con el código para que comprenda qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

EL problema claramente indica que no coinciden las dimensiones de la variable de retorno de tu función en donde las quieres almacenar. Buscaría revisar la variable 't' en tu función de Euler  que para multiplicarla por un vector generalmente hay que usar el signo de `.` antecediendo el operador de multiplicación. Otra observación es revisar que coincida en tu ´tic´ de tu main.

Como recomendación creo vale la pena que pongas en líneas separadas aquellas instrucciones que al final contengan un `;` para que sea un poco más legible